# Find the derivative by using the quotient rule. Simplify answer.

Tags: calculus

Can someone please check my answer?

$$f(x)= \frac{x^2+3x-1}{x-1}$$

$$(x-1)[x^2+3x-1]-(x^2+3x-1)[x-1]$$

$$(x-1)(2x+3)-(x^2+3x-1)(1)$$
$$2x^2+3x-2x-3-x^2+3x-1$$
$$2x^2+x-3-x^2+3x-1$$
$$x^2-2x-2=$$

answer: 
$$x^2-2x-2/(x-1)^2$$

I hope it's not too confusing to look at. Thank you very much!

Comment: Going from $(x-1)(2x+3)-(x^2+3x-1)(1)$ to 
$2x^2+3x-2x-3-x^2+3x-1$ is technically wrong, it should be $2x^2+3x-2x-3-x^2-3x+1$. Now in fact that is in fact what you meant, and the ultimate simplification is correct. But doing things in this way invites "accidents."

Comment: (2x^2+3x-2x-3)-(x^2+3x-1)   can I write it like this?

Comment: Yes, that is the best way of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 + 3x -1}{x-1}.$$

If $f(x) = p(x)/q(x),$ then $f' = (p'q - q'p)/q^2,$ so

$$f'(x) = \frac{(2x+3)(x-1) - (1)(x^2+3x-1)}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{x^2-2x-2}{(x-1)^2}.$$

So ... I think you got it.

Comment: I hope I got it right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your answer at all -- how did dividing by $x$ turn into dividing by $(x-1)$?

Here are two methods to arrive at the answer.

You can term-by-term differentiate:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg( x^2 + 3x - 1 - \frac{1}{x}\bigg) = 2x + 3 - \frac{d}{dx}x^{-1} = 2x + 3 + x^{-2}.$$
Alternatively, write the Laurent polynomial as a rational function:
$$ x^2 + 3x - 1 - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x^3 + 3x^2 - x - 1}{x}.$$

Now you can use the quotient rule.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do these things, IMO (assuming you're doing this as part of a relatively early calc class) is to use the quotient rule: bottom times derivative of the top minus the top times derivative of the bottom over the bottom squared. Or, mathematically:

$$f(x) = \frac{p(x}{q(x)} \rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{q(x)p'(x)-p(x)q'(x)}{(q(x))^2}$$

first take the derivative of the top: $2x+3$
then the derviative of the bottom: $1$

which gets you: $$f'(x)=\frac{(x-1)(2x+3)-(x^2+3x-1)(1)}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{(2x^2+3x-2x-3)-(x^2+3x-1)}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{(x^2-2x-2)}{(x-1)^2}$$

what i did looks complicated and it is to a degree, but I like to show all the algebraic steps because it makes it clearer what's happening and for me anyway, it's easier to keep track.